# Route component only loading after page refresh?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular7

After I log in my application and try to change routes, the URL changes but the component doesn't load.

I have tried reordering the routes in different ways but that also doesn't seem to work.

My app-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'settings', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'manage-labels', component: ManageLabelsComponent, data: { title: 'Manage Labels' } },
      { path: 'profile-settings', component: ProfileSettingsComponent, data: { title: 'Profile Settings' } },
      { path: '', component: SettingsComponent, data: { title: 'Settings' } }
    ]
  },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { title: 'Home' }, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: { title: 'About Us' } },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: 'Login' } },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { title: 'Page Not Found' } }

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard]
})
```

I find it weird that it needs to refresh to "load" the routes. Perhaps routes aren't loaded after login?

Edit: Specifically the settings component. I've also tried having it as a single route with not children and that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ? Could you provide a [mcve] of your issue ?

Comment: @trichetriche
I do not get errors in the console. At the moment I cannot provide an example.

But basically after I log in I load the HomeComponent(which is empty for now, exept for a test string). 

I have a navbar where after i click on settings(routerlink to 'settings'), it navigates to localhost:4200/settings(here it still displays the HomeComponent).

If I refresh on localhost:4200/settings the settings component then loads.

Comment: perhaps something wrong with the AuthGuard? could you remove it and check.

Comment: @Haijin Yes I have actually tried that sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: You might use the router's enableTracing option to see a little deeper what's happending.